# Unexpected Issues raised on test files

Tags: java, sonarqube

[image]

This FindBugs issue is raised on a test file. Those test files should not be analyzed by SonarQube as source code. They don't seem to be by having a look at the log (test files are in "testsrc" directory).

-------------  Scan xxx origin/master
2015-05-08 11:13:25 11:13:25.341 INFO  - Load module settings
...
2015-05-08 11:13:25 11:13:25.557 INFO  - Source paths: src, hmc/src
2015-05-08 11:13:25 11:13:25.557 INFO  - Test paths: testsrc
2015-05-08 11:13:25 11:13:25.557 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
...

and by the fact that NOSONAR issue is not raised on this file.

So, it looks like the FindBugs analysis reported an issue on this test file and SonarQube decorated this test file with the issue. How is it possible?

Configuration:

- SonarQube 5.0
- Java plugin 3.1

Comment: Are you using Maven to analyse this project @David ? Because if this is not the case, one possible explanation is that bytecode classes from sources and tests and generated into the same "bin" directory and in that case indeed the Findbugs plugin can starting generating some issues on test files.

Comment: We're using Ant. Bytecode of the source code is not generated in the same folder as the test code. It seems to happen randomly. I don't know why. So let's close this ticket for now.